# Undefined index 'PWD' in $_server

Tags: php

I got this error when I am trying to run a simple PhP script via php.exe. The name of the script is gulliver ( no extension), and I type this into my command prompt:

```
php %Dir%\gulliver
```

Here's the content in the gulliver file:

```
<?php
//***************** Operating Systems parameters  **************************
  if ( PHP_OS == 'WINNT' ) 
    define('PATH_SEP', '\\');
  else
    define('PATH_SEP', '/');

//***************** Defining the Home Directory *********************************
  $docuroot =  explode ( PATH_SEP , $_SERVER['PWD'] );
```

The error occured was **PHP notice: Undefined index: PWD in %Directory%gulliver.**

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: If it helps anyone when running a script via sudo (such as sudo my_script.php) then I don't see $_SERVER['pwd'] when otherwise I do.

Comment: @Alistair: Thanks for the hint. Reason behind it is, [that `PWD` (Posix Ohter Environment Variables)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03) is an environment variable and not all are kept by `sudo` command by default. See [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/367456).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find PWD in the [manual page for $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). To find out which indexes are defined use [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump)($_SERVER);

If you need the "current working directory", use the [getcwd](http://php.net/getcwd)() function.

PS:
Instead of defining your own PATH_SEP, you could use the predefined constant DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.

Comment: $_SERVER['PWD'] is not strictly an equivalent to getcwd() because getcwd resolves symlinks, which can cause problems in some situations (happened with drush module)

Answer (score 1):

So, you execute the script through the CLI version of the interpreter and expect to see the $_SERVER array? Which is populated when a script is executed through a web server?

Comment: The cli version also includes a (filled) $_SERVER array. It includes all environment variables amongst others. I agree the naming of the $_SERVER is weird. But that just shows PHP is designed for the web.