# How to keep environment variables when using sudo

Tags: linux, environment-variables, sudo

When I use any command with sudo the environment variables are not there. For example after setting `HTTP_PROXY` the command `wget` works fine without `sudo`. However if I type `sudo wget` it says it can't bypass the proxy setting.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables

Comment: Related: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix SE

Answer (score 381, accepted):

The trick is to add environment variables to `sudoers` file via `sudo visudo` command and add these lines:

```
Defaults env_keep += "ftp_proxy http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy"
```

taken from [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Environment_variables).

For Ubuntu 14, you need to specify in separate lines as it returns the errors for multi-variable lines:

```
Defaults  env_keep += "http_proxy"
Defaults  env_keep += "https_proxy"
Defaults  env_keep += "HTTP_PROXY"
Defaults  env_keep += "HTTPS_PROXY"
```

Comment: This is arguably the best option, to avoid information leakage and security holes. `sudo -E` is the sure-fire way to adhoc get the same effect for a one-off, though

Comment: I encountered the problem of a process being the one who call sudo (jhbuild) and i can't tell it to pass the -E flag to sudo, so this is my solution.

Comment: Notice that you should *never* edit the `etc/sudoers` directly. Instead, use the `visudo` command, which syntax-checks your edits before overwriting the `sudoers` file. That way, you don't lock yourself out if you make a mistake while editing.

Comment: Consider using uppercase env vars. In my case the use of HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY did the trick.

Comment: The syntax to restrict the Defaults to a command or user is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13246/66983

Comment: lowercase variant is better from my experience as it works in both wget and curl.

Comment: Does editing / appending new environment variables this way take effect right away? Or does it require a server restart? I can't seem to preserve my `~/.bash_profile` exported vars even after using `sudo visudo` to add them with `Defaults  env_keep += "VARNAME"`

Comment: (continue.) Nevermind, realized I was placing it too early, before the `Defaults env_reset`, haaa! Glad I figured that one out!

Comment: this won't work if your env. variables are set via ~/.profile

Comment: I think this applies even to ubuntu 22.04, single liner did not work for me.

Answer (score 658):

First you need to `export HTTP_PROXY`. Second, you need to read `man sudo`, and look at the `-E` flag. This works:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=foof
$ sudo -E bash -c 'echo $HTTP_PROXY'
```

Here is the quote from the man page:

```
-E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
             existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
             if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

Comment: great the only problem that is modify some config files for example pacman for arch to make the -E is passed

Comment: To allow -E (preserve environment) for wget, you need to specify the SETENV tag on the sudo rule that allows the running of wget -- Example:  <username> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:SETENV: <path to wget>

Comment: This "-E" doesn't work if the variable is PATH or PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Also doesn't work with any `LC_*` variable. So just do `export LOL_FOO=$LC_FOO` and use `LOL_FOO` instead.

Comment: This did not work with the simpler case of adding one element to the `PATH` in the `.bashrc` file -- say, `export PATH=myPath:$PATH`. If I type `sudo -E bash -c 'echo $PATH'`, then `PATH` does not contain myPath probably because `sudo` has already disabled the local value of `PATH` before calling `bash`. Rather, I found the answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/33183620/5459638 effective, that is `sudo PATH=$PATH command`

Comment: Addition to the comment above. Say that `package` is under myPath, then `sudo PATH=$PATH which package` finds the right answer unlike `sudo which package`. However, `sudo PATH=$PATH package` does not go any further than `sudo package` (file not found). On the other hand, launching a plain `package` from a shell invoked with `sudo bash` preserves the extended path and gives `package` sudo rights (two pigeons with one stone). So the response really depends on which commands you are launching

Comment: The (setter) user may not have permission to keep environment variables: `-E, --preserve-env
                 ... .  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.`

Comment: @XavierStuvw It's an "obvious" security measure not allowing PATH by default, since the user could inadvertently execute some non-standard command with UN-expected results and root privileges.

Comment: Remember, you can always set environment variables inline as well: `HTTP_PROXY=val sudo -E bash -c 'echo $HTTP_PROXY'`.

Comment: this won't work if your env. variables are set via ~/.profile

Comment: For the system I'm using, I did not have permission to run bash with sudo, but simply running `sudo -E <command>` worked. +1

Answer (score 94):

For individual variables you want to make available on a one off basis you can make it part of the command.

```
sudo http_proxy=$http_proxy wget "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: I have tested this answer for a `package` under some myPath added to `PATH` in the `.bashrc` file (with `export` clausule). Then `sudo PATH=$PATH which package` finds the right answer, unlike `sudo which package`. However, `sudo PATH=$PATH package` does not go any further than `sudo package` (file not found). On the other hand, launching a plain `package` from a shell invoked with `sudo bash` preserves the extended path and gives `package` sudo rights (two pigeons with one stone). So the response really depends on which commands you are launching

Comment: PATH resolution for sudo is another matter - should anyone find this post in search of that matter I suggest seeing http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path

Comment: notice the order of the arguments is important, first `sudo`, only *then* the environment variable to be forwarded, then the command with its arguments.

Answer (score 27):

You can also combine the two `env_keep` statements in Ahmed Aswani's answer into a single statement like this:

`Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"`

You should also consider specifying `env_keep` for only a single command like this:

`Defaults!/bin/[your_command] env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"`

Answer (score 13):

## A simple wrapper function (or in-line for loop)

I came up with a unique solution because:

- `sudo -E "$@"` was leaking variables that was causing problems for my command
- `sudo VAR1="$VAR1" ... VAR42="$VAR42" "$@"` was long and ugly in my case

### demo.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function sudo_exports(){
    eval sudo $(for x in $_EXPORTS; do printf '%q=%q ' "$x" "${!x}"; done;) "$@"
}

# create a test script to call as sudo
echo 'echo Forty-Two is $VAR42' > sudo_test.sh
chmod +x sudo_test.sh

export VAR42="The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything."

export _EXPORTS="_EXPORTS VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6 VAR7 VAR8 VAR9 VAR10 VAR11 VAR12 VAR13 VAR14 VAR15 VAR16 VAR17 VAR18 VAR19 VAR20 VAR21 VAR22 VAR23 VAR24 VAR25 VAR26 VAR27 VAR28 VAR29 VAR30 VAR31 VAR32 VAR33 VAR34 VAR35 VAR36 VAR37 VAR38 VAR39 VAR40 VAR41 VAR42"

# clean function style
sudo_exports ./sudo_test.sh

# or just use the content of the function
eval sudo $(for x in $_EXPORTS; do printf '%q=%q ' "$x" "${!x}"; done;) ./sudo_test.sh
```

#### Result

```
$ ./demo.sh
Forty-Two is The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything.
Forty-Two is The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything.
```

### How?

This is made possible by a feature of the bash builtin `printf`. The `%q` produces a shell quoted string. Unlike [the parameter expansion in bash 4.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379190/9745), this works in bash versions < 4.0

Answer (score 4):

#### Add code snippets to /etc/sudoers.d

Don't know if this is available in all distros, but in Debian-based distros, there is a line at or near the tail of the `/etc/sudoers` file that includes the folder `/etc/sudoers.d`. Herein, one may [add code *"snippets"*](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo#The_include_directive) that modify sudo's configuration. Specifically, they allow control over all environment variables used in `sudo`.

As with `/etc/sudoers`, these *"code snippets"* should be edited using `visudo`. You can start by reading the `README` file, which is also a handy place for keeping any notes you care to make:

```sh
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/README 

# files for your snippets may be created/edited like so:

$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/20_mysnippets
```

#### Read the "Command Environment" section of 'man 5 sudoers'

Perhaps the most informative documentation on environment configuration in `sudo` is found in the `Command environment` section of `man 5 sudoers`. Here, we learn that a *sudoers* environment variables that are blocked by default may be *"whitelisted"* using the `env_check` or `env_keep` options; e.g.

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy HTTP_PROXY"
Defaults env_keep += "https_proxy HTTPS_PROXY"
Defaults env_keep += "ftp_proxy FTP_PROXY"
```

And so, in the OP's case, we may "pass" the *sudoer's* environment variables as follows:

```sh
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/10_myenvwlist

# opens the default editor for entry of the following lines: 
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy HTTP_PROXY"
Defaults env_keep += "https_proxy HTTPS_PROXY"
# and any others deemed useful/necessary
# Save the file, close the editor, and you are done!
```

#### Get your bearings from '# sudo -V'

The OP presumably discovered the missing environment variable in `sudo` by *trial-and-error*. However, it is possible to be proactive: A listing of all environment variables, and their allowed or denied status is available (and unique to each host) from the `root` prompt as follows:

```sh
# sudo -V
...
Environment variables to check for safety: 
...
Environment variables to remove: 
...
Environment variables to preserve:
...
```

Note that once an environment variable is "whitelisted" as above, it will appear in subsequent listings of `sudo -V` under the "preserve" listing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the need to keep the environment variables in a script you can put your command in a here document like this. Especially if you have lots of variables to set things look tidy this way.

```sh
# prepare a script e.g. for running maven
runmaven=/tmp/runmaven$$
# create the script with a here document 
cat << EOF > $runmaven
#!/bin/bash
# run the maven clean with environment variables set
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export MAKEFLAGS=-j4
mvn clean install
EOF
# make the script executable
chmod +x $runmaven
# run it
sudo $runmaven
# remove it or comment out to keep
rm $runmaven
```