# Error setting environment variables in python

Tags: python, environment-variables, bloomberg

I am trying to use Bloomberg python API. I need to set BLPAPI_ROOT environment variable for this. I added,

```
export BLPAPI_ROOT="/home/user/Downloads/blpapi_cpp_3.6.3.1"
export PATH=$PATH:$BLPAPI_ROOT
```

to my .bashrc file and ran source .bashrc.
Now, when I open python shell and do,

```
print os.environ['BLPAPI_ROOT']
```

it gives me correct output. But when the same this runs inside the setup.py provided, it throws a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    blpapiRoot = os.environ['BLPAPI_ROOT']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'BLPAPI_ROOT'
```

What am I missing here ?

System :
Ubuntu 12.04
Python 2.7

Comment: The error will occur when you run your script with another security context e.g. using sudo

Comment: But without sudo,I get permission denied as it is trying to access /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blpapi. Is there a correct way of doing this that I am missing ?

Comment: Maybe use `chmod` to change permissions for that folder and then try.

Comment: is there a solution for the same problem using windows and python version 3.9 ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using it the following way:

```
import os
try:
    os.environ['BLPAPI_ROOT'] = "/home/user/Downloads/blpapi_cpp_3.6.3.1"
except EnvironmentError:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but for anyone searching, you can get around this by setting sudo to keep the environmental variable BLPAPI_ROOT, a la [keep environmental variables using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add:

```
Defaults env_keep +="BLPAPI_ROOT"
```

You can now run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: It's not working in my case. Perhaps because i'm inside a virtualenv?