# Node Server on Ubuntu can't access environment variables as sudo

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I'm running a Node/Express web server on an AWS EC2 box with Ubuntu server 12.04, and I set 4 environment variables in the .bashrc file to access my database. If I run the server as a normal user, it works fine. However, if I run node as sudo, the environment variables are undefined.

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables are not passed to `sudo`: [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

> the trick is to add enviroment variables to sudoers config:
>
> ```
> sudo visudo
> ```
>
> add these lines
>
> ```
> Defaults env_keep +="http_proxy"
> Defaults env_keep +="https_proxy"
> ```
>
> form ArchLinux wiki
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Environment_variables_.28Outdated.3F.29

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using the right language to search successfully.