# Can't access environment variable from node.js in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, environment-variables

I created an Ubuntu micro instance on AWS, installed node and everything.
I have some API credentials in my node.js app, that I'd like to store in environment variables. I'm not Linux savy, so I googled and found that best way to store these variables permanently is to edit etc/environment.
I did so, and this is how it looks:

```
NO_OF_DAYS=30
REFRESH_INTERVAL_MINS=30
API_PASSWORD="**pppp!!"
API_USERNAME="johnny88!"
```

I rebooted system after this change, as I read it is needed.

Yet when I try to access these variables in my node.js app, with i.e. process.env.API_PASSWORD or process.env.NO_OF_DAYS, it just returns undefined as a value.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @shellter: `/etc/environment` is not a shell script, it only contain variable definition that will be set system wide. `export` won't work.

Comment: @kecman: '/etc/environment' does not allows quoting, put the value as it: `API_USERNAME=toto`

Comment: @Cyrbil : Thanks for sharing, (obviously) I didn't know that ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: I deleted other entries and left only NO_OF_DAYS and REFRESH_INTERVAL_MINS, rebooted Ubuntu, and I still get undefined as a value of process.env.NO_OF_DAYS.
And there was already an entry with quotes, some PATH=".....", so it should work with quotes?

Comment: I just have realized that when I call my node.js app with "node app.js" it gets the value as it should, and I used to run it with "sudo node app.js"

Comment: Do you know why this is? having a similar problem

Comment: @s_kirkiles I guess because sudo uses different enviroment variables, and I set my environment variables without sudo, so I have to run app.js with just "node app.js" instead of "sudo node app.js"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Server on Ubuntu can't access environment variables as sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690644/node-server-on-ubuntu-cant-access-environment-variables-as-sudo)