# How to keep some variable with su -?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, su

It is possible to keep some variable when users do "su - xxx" (i know that "-" will erase the environment variable, but i am asking if others solutions or possibilities  exists) ?

Thanks !

Comment: give a glance to this [link][1]

i hope it's what you'd to do.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 2):

Use -m

eg

su -m xxxx

```
-m, --preserve-environment
              do not reset environment variables
```

[online manpage with additional information](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/su1.html)
(PATH and IFS might be changed nevertheless)