# Can't pass environment variables to Rails only when running 'rails server' with '-b' or '-p'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I set environment variables at `.bash_profile` as below for Oauth

```
export TWITTER_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
export TWITTER_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If I run just `rails server` without any option to boot WEBrick, `ENV['TWITTER_KEY']` and `ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']` can be accessed properly. But If running it with options like `sudo rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 80`, it can't. These doesn't seem to be passed to Rails.

Why?

I use

```
Mac OSX 10.9.5
ruby 2.1.2p95
Rails 4.2.0.beta2
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Comment: Thanks, @FrederickCheung ! As you said, the reason is that environment variables aren't succeeded to `sudo`, because `visudo` doesn't specify the name of those variables. Now I've modified visudo and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to own question myself. As Frederick and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) told, the reason was that environment variables aren't succeeded to sudo, because visudo doesn't specify the name of those variables.

So I added the lines below to visudo, and it works.

```
Defaults        env_keep += "TWITTER_KEY"
Defaults        env_keep += "TWITTER_SECRET"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some step by step instructions:

1. Open up your bash profile
   `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add the environment variable to the file `export TWITTER_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxx`
3. Open up the sudoers config file `sudo visudo`
4. Add the following line to the file exactly as so `Defaults        env_keep +="TWITTER_KEY"`

Now when you run the command with sudo it should work as desired, with TWITTER_KEY set to xxxxxxxxxxxxx.