# How to set GOPATH in Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: go, gocql

I installed Go 1.4 in Mac OS X. Previously I had Go 1.0. I set the GOROOT and PATH as follows,

```
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ export GOROOT=/usr/local/go/bin/go
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Go is installed in '/usr/local/go/bin/go'. And I set the GOPATH as my project src directory. I am able to run go code inside my directory. But when I try to install gocql I am getting error.

```
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ sudo go get github.com/gocql/gocql
package github.com/gocql/gocql: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Could anyone help me on this? Thank you

**EDIT 1:** @VonC I tried the other option as well. I changed the GOROOT to the directory where go is installed. But it didn't help. And I changed the GOPATH.

```
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ export GOPATH=/Users/Dany/Documents/FALL-2013-COURSES/Imp_Data_structures/workspace/go-cassandra
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ sudo go get github.com/gocql/gocql
Password:
package github.com/gocql/gocql: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/Dany/Documents/FALL-2013-COURSES/Imp_Data_structures/workspace/go-cassandra
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$ ls
bin pkg src
Dineshs-MacBook-Air:go-cassandra Dany$
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Notes:

`GOROOT` should reference a folder (where go is installed), not the `go` executable itself

```bash
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

As [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c) mentions in the comments, you should not have to set `GOROOT` at all in your case.
See the article [You don’t need to set `GOROOT`, really](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really).

`GOPATH` should reference a folder under which you will find `src`, `pkg` and `bin`. (it should not reference directly the `src` folder):
See "[How to Write Go Code - Workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)"

Regarding the `GOPATH`:

- try and set it in your `~/.bashrc` (using `export`).
- check that your current shell is a bash (and not another one like `fish`)
- check the output of `go env`.

Don't do a `sudo go get`, as the environment variable used for `sudo` (`root`) wouldn't be the same as the current user:

```
go get github.com/gocql/gocql
```

(or [you would need to do a `sudo -E bash -c 'go get github.com/gocql/gocql'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/6309), but I suspect you don't need `root` here)

See [sudo caveat](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#sudo_caveat):

> Any variables added to these locations will not be reflected when invoking them with a `sudo` command, as `sudo` has a default policy of resetting the Environment and setting a secure path (this behavior is defined in `/etc/sudoers`)

Comment: I tried. But still facing the same issue. I edited the question with the current GOPATH and GOROOT

Comment: Thank you. It worked without sudo. Could you explain me how it works. ? I am new to mac.

Comment: [You don’t need to set GOROOT](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) and you normally don't want to.

Comment: @DaveC I have seen that before. I always set it anyway because I always unzip my go installation package in a non-conventional path (I am that "Windows user using the zip binary downloaded from the golang.org website"). I have included the link to the article in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC, that's one of the exceptions specifically mentioned in the article. I set it too (for other reasons, like I find it convenient to do things like `grep $GOROOT/src/…` from time to time). The idea though is don't start out setting it or advising others to do so unless there is a specific need.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to inform to **Go** the location of your workspace. In this example we gonna use $HOME/dev/go-workspace.

Then you need to know if your mac have zsh or bash configured as shell.

> The file ~/.zshrc is used for zsh shell. The zsh shell was introduced
> in macOS Catalina.
>
> The ~/.bashrc is the bash shell used in previews OS version, the same for linux users.

1: Add those lines to export the required variables in your ~/.zsh or ~./bashrc depending on your shell.

For go installed from original pkg download from https://golang.org/doc/install

```bash
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go-workspace
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

For Go installed from home brew. (brew update and brew install golang)

```bash
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go-workspace
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

2: run

```bash
# source ~/.zshrc
```

or

```bash
source ~./bashrc
```

to update your $PATH according with the new variables inserted in step #2

3: Then create your the workspace directories:

```bash
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH $GOPATH/src $GOPATH/pkg $GOPATH/bin
```

4: create a test.go, the hello world

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Run your program by executing:

```
$ go run test.go
```

If you wish to compile it and move it to $GOPATH/bin, then run:

```
$ go install test.go
```

Since we have $GOPATH/bin added to your $PATH, you can run your program from anywhere just typing test :

```
$ test
```

If everything is right the output will be :

```
hello, world
```

Answer (score 4):

### tldr;

macos terminal:

```bash
brew install go
```

edit ~/.zshenv

```bash
export GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.6/libexec"
export GOPATH="/Users/Shared/Development/go-workspace"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

Think of the **GOPATH** in terms of a configured workspace for the environment. **GOROOT** is the install point for the go language. Homebrew will symlink the bin commands to your /usr/local/bin. Add the **$GOPATH** to your **PATH** in order to find any go programs that you later install.

Comment: Thanks! for me just the 1st step was sufficient.
brew install go

Answer (score 0):

I face many issues to set the GOROOT and GOPATH in MacOS, and the only solution that worked for me, is the below one:

Add the following code into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` if you use [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) `~/.zshrc`

```bash
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

After that, run the following command in your terminal:

```bash
source ~/.profile
```

If you have any different shell, replace it in the place of `.profile`.

**Info:** `$HOME` variable will point to your current user's directory.

**Info 2:** `/usr/local/go` is where all users, the go files, and bin folder exists.

**To Set Custom GOPATH as working directory:**

To store your projects of **GoLang** in different folders, you can set the custom path. Here is my custom GOPATH, which points to my goWorkSpace folder in my admin/Documents folder.

```bash
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/goWorkSpace
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `$PATH` incorrectly. `$GOROOT` is set **and** added to the `$PATH` during installation. So neither:

```bash
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go/bin/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

nor:

```bash
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

is needed because `$GOROOT` will be different based on how you've installed Go - Homebrew, [go.dev](https://go.dev/doc/install), etc.

**You just need to set `$GOPATH`.**

If you find [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory) useful (this will keep your `$HOME` clean), you could:

- Create a user-specific data directory

  ```bash
  mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/go
  ```
- Set `$GOPATH` in `.zshenv`

  ```bash
  export GOPATH="$HOME/.local/share/go"
  export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
  ```
- Refresh environment variables

  ```bash
  source .zshenv
  # or quit and re-open the shell
  ```
- Install Go package

  ```bash
  go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
  ```
- Verify version of package

  ```bash
  which gopls
  ```