# Why do the environment variables set in command prompt have no effect when I start Spyder

Tags: python, environment-variables, spyder, theano

I am using the Spyder Anaconda IDE for Python. I am writing a code in the Spyder IDE that requires few environment variables to be set ($CPATH, $LIBRARY_PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) for the Theano library.

I am starting Spyder using the command

```
sudo ./spyder
```

and it starts fine. Even though I set the environment variables in my

```
/root/.bashrc
```

file, the code still fails to accept the path and if I try printing

```
print os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
```

it raises a KeyError.

I tried all the above with a normal user but still it fails. How can I get Spyder IDE to be able to view files in the above paths and where can I set them inside Spyder?

Comment: Try sudo env. This will separate problems with spyder with problems with the shell not running .bashrc

Comment: `.bashrc` is only read for interactive shells

Comment: try to  declare variables directly in your code: `os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]="exact/path/to/folder"`

Comment: @Andersson I even did setting using os.environ. It doesn't work :(.

Comment: @RobertJacobs I did a sudo env and it prints lots of environment variables. I do not see my variables in the list. Is that a concern?

Comment: Can you add the env variables before sudo ? Or run a script that sets them before calling spyder. Or run sudo -i ,then run spyder.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It finally works only when I do "sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib CPATH=/usr/lib python <file_name.py>". Which means only if I set it in the command line before running the file it runs fine. Setting it in /root/.bashrc doesn't help at all.

Comment: This is maybe a silly question, but why do you need to run your editor as root?  In particular, preserving `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as an environment variable probably has more serious security implications than you might think, and I wonder if you need it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the `sudoers` file which Environmental Variables to keep when using the `sudo` command.

To edit the sudoers file run.

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add the following line to the end of it.

```
Defaults env_keep = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH CPATH LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Then `export` your variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library"
```

Now you should be able to run it.

More info can be found here [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

Comment: I am trying this now.

Comment: Can you help me append more environment variables to keep? Should I just leave a space within the quotes and add more ?I have 3 of them

Comment: I am trying this now.

Comment: This is generally a **very bad** advice. Exactly those envirnoment vairables are not preseved by sudo because keeping them is a **big security risk**. The avdice should be to create a wrapper script or not executing an IDE as root in the first place, _not_ allowing sudo to preserve insecure environment variables.