# Java getenv() returns null

Tags: java, linux, shell, null, getenv

I'm defining an environment variable in a Linux shell with `TestEnviron=varproperty`. Now, I want to write a small program that reads the environment variable, writes it to the console output, and writes the variable to a properties file. However when I try it with this code `getenv()` returns `null`:

```
package javaenvironmentvariable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JavaEnvironmentVariable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String variable = System.getenv("TestEnviron");
            System.out.println("TestEnviron: " + variable);
            variable = "TestEnviron=" + variable;

            Properties properties = new Properties();

            File file = new File("Variables.properties");
            FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            properties.store(fileout, variable);
            fileout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I use this in the shell to call the jar: `sudo java -jar JavaEnvironmentVariable.jar`

Comment: How did you define your variable in the shell ? Do you run your program right after defining it or in another shell ? How do you launch your program ?

Comment: If you use another shell to launch your program use `export` to define your var: `export TestEnviron=varproperty`

Comment: @perencia I used TestEnviron=varproperty in the stell, and right after that i run my programm with this sudo java -jar JavaEnvironmentVariable.jar in the same shell.

Comment: @nickbijmoer you get your variable if you do `env` in your shell ?

Comment: Why use `sudo`? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) for more info on `sudo` and env vars. You can launch your program with `sudo -E` to keep your environment in sudo.

Comment: Reac what @AndreaGhidini told you. You missed the `export` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sudo -E` AND `export` to keep the environment variables:

```
$ export TestEnviron=varproperty
$ sudo -E java -jar JavaEnvironmentVariable.jar
```

However to be more safe you should configure sudo to keep your variable as explained in this post: [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) :

```
sudo visudo
```

and add this line:

```
Defaults env_keep += "TestEnviron"
```

Comment: Yeah thats the solution! thanks a lot! I did not know that sudo wont keep the environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Shells don't automatically put their variables into the environment. You need to explicitly export the variable using `export ENVVAR=VALUE` or `set -x ENVVAR VALUE` depending on your shell.

Comment: It didn't work because I used sudo apparently but thanks for the export tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your are setting the environment variable in one shell and executing your program in another shell. Try to execute both in a same shell. Before executing the program check by printing the environment variable in shell.

Comment: I am executing them in the same shell but still get null, I printed the variable with this code: echo $TestEnviron and then it returns varproperty so thats fine.