# Where to set system default environment variables in Alpine linux?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, default, alpine-linux

I know, with Ubuntu, you can set default values for environment variables in `/etc/environment`; I do not see that file in Alpine linux. Is there a different location for setting system-wide defaults?

Comment: how about here /etc/lbu/lbu.conf

Comment: @Rick not seeing the effect. do you know of any good documentation for this in Alpine? or do you have more details, tips, tricks, with setting envars in Alpine?

Comment: I'm looking for  the answer also... Have you found anything yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found much. The only other information I found is from https://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/config-notes.html under the header "Configuration Inheritance"

Comment: @Rick that is not the right Alpine; your URL refers to the Alpine Mail User Agent, not to the minimal container-adapted Linux-based OS.

Comment: Having the same issue here

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems that `/etc/profile` is the best place I could find. At least, some environment variables are set there:

```
export CHARSET=UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '

umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
        if [ -r $script ] ; then
                . $script
        fi
done
```

According to the contents of `/etc/profile`, you can create a file with `.sh` extension in `/etc/profile.d/` and you have to pass `--login` every time to load the env variables e.g `docker exec -it container sh --login`.

Comment: yes, `/etc/profile` and/or `/etc/profile.d/` were what I ended up using. makes sense

Comment: How do you get `/etc/profile` to run automatically when you start an alpine docker container interactively? I have added some aliases to an `aliases.sh` file and placed it in `/etc/profile.d`, but when I start the container using `docker run -it [my_container] sh`, my aliases aren't active. I have to manually type `. /etc/profile` from the command line each time. Is there some other configuration necessary to get `/etc/profile` to run at login? Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: @JeffKilbride use `sh --login` instead of just `sh`.

Comment: @VladFrolov Thanks! I asked this question in another thread and got an answer there, too. This also works:  `sh -l`.

Comment: other very nice thing to have in hand is `sudo -i <command>`. I had to export a http proxy, everytime I had to run something that installed things from internet, I had to `sudo su` then `export http.....` then `apk blabla`.. now `sudo -i apk add whatever`

Comment: @Tonsic you may find interesting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) for keeping environment variables with sudo.

Comment: For anyone wondering. This also works for non-root user cronjobs. E.g. using a Docker container running crond as root. And having a crontab for user foo that runs a cronjob that needs environment variables from the /etc/profile.

Answer (score 17):

If you are talking about Alpine Docker image, then you can define those env variables inside Dockerfile like below. Here you don't need to pass `--login` every time. These variables will be automatically available system wide globally.

```
FROM alpine
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    COMPOSER_HOME=/home/deploy/.composer
```

Also you can define your alias, env etc inside /etc/profile and define a `ENV` inside Dockerfile like below to source the profile automatically.

```
FROM alpine
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    COMPOSER_HOME=/home/deploy/.composer
ENV ENV="/etc/profile"
```

Comment: This is actually a very nice alternative without the overhead of --login. Thank you!

Comment: A quick note: values set by `ENV` will be inherited by all other docker images that use your image as `FROM`. It may have unexpected consequences when your `/etc/profile` is available in other child images