# Path is different depending on how you connect to container

Tags: docker, ssh, path, alpine-linux

I have an Alpine docker container and depending on how I connect using ssh the path is different. If I connect using a PTY shell:

`ssh root@localhost sh -lc env | grep PATH`

this prints:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

However if don't use this shell:

`ssh root@localhost sh -c env | grep PATH`

this prints:

`PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin`

Why is this happening? What do I need to do so that the second command produces the same output as the first command?

Comment: If you are really ssh'ing to a container, then the value of `$PATH` is not your biggest problem, really. https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: @CarlosGranados what alpine image exactly are you using? I think SSH is not part of a default alpine image. Actually I don't understand why people always want to SSH into containers. Why not use `docker exec`?

Comment: @dpr and the other person with an impossible name: I am not ssh'ing by choice, it is a tool that is doing it and I am trying to fix that tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. This stack overflow post has the main info needed: [Where to set system default environment variables in Alpine linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325856/where-to-set-system-default-environment-variables-in-alpine-linux)

Given that, there are two alternatives:

- Declare `PATH` using the `ENV` option of the `Dockerfile`
- Or add `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to `sshd_config` file and define PATH in `~/.ssh/environment`

Comment: How does this explain the difference between the different `sh` options?

Comment: If you pass the -l (or --login) option it will read the /etc/profile file. If you don't, it won't read it and you need to use one of the other alternatives I posted

Comment: Ok, I thought you mentioned that no `/etc/profile` was present in the image...

Answer (score 1):

With `sh -l` you start a login shell:

> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the **--login** option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order. The **--noprofile** option may be used to inhibit this behavior.
> ...
> A non-interactive shell invoked with the name **sh** does not attempt to read any other startup files.

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh

That is you can probably edit the profile files to make the login shell behave similar to `noprofile` but it might become difficult the other way around.