# Bash - How to force literal in subshell string?

Tags: bash, variables, sudo, variable-expansion

I'd like to control variable expansion when executing a shell command using `sudo bash -c`.

I know I can do it from a normal shell:

```
bash$ export FOO=foo
bash$ export BAR=bar
bash$ echo "expand $FOO but not "'$BAR'""
expand foo but not $BAR
```

How can I do the above using `sudo bash -c`?

```
bash$ sudo bash -c "echo "expand $FOO but not "'$BAR'"""
expand
bash$ sudo bash -c 'echo "expand $FOO but not "'$BAR'""'
expand  but not bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this with escaped `$` that you don't want to expand:

```
$> bash -c "echo \"expand $FOO but not \"'\$BAR'"
expand foo but not $BAR
```

However I recommend using here-doc to avoid escaping:

```
# original echo replaced with printf
$> printf 'expand %s but not %s\n' "$FOO" '$BAR'
expand foo but not $BAR

# prints in here-doc with bash
$> bash<<-'EOF'
printf 'expand %s but not %s\n' "$FOO" '$BAR'
EOF
expand foo but not $BAR
```

Comment: For here-doc, use sudo -E to work in root env.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 0):

Pass arguments rather than trying to generate a string to pass to `bash`.

```
$ bash -c 'echo "expand $1 but not $2"' _ "$FOO" '$BAR'
expand 5 but not $BAR
```

(The `_` is just a dummy value to set `$0` in the script specified by `-c`.)