# Can't access environment variable in Rust

Tags: rust, environment-variables, rust-cargo

The piece of code is as follows:

```
// Log in to Discord using a bot token from the environment                  
let discord = Discord::from_bot_token(                                       
    &env::var("DISCORD_TOKEN").unwrap()                                      
).expect("login failed");
```

I get an error saying it is unable to find the environment variable `DISCORD_TOKEN`.

My environment does show the variable:

```
myawesomename$env | grep DISCORD
DISCORD_TOKEN=you'llneverknow
```

If I print all the keys and values that Rust knows:

```
for (key, value) in env::vars() {                                            
    println!("{}: {}", key, value);                                      
}
```

It doesn't show the environment variable.

On a similar note, when I do `env | grep CARGO`, none of the CARGO variables exist, but they are printed in the Rust code.

There is something I fundamentally doesn't understand about the profile/system env variables Rust is looking at (which, I assumed, are the variables in the environment in which the process is launched).

**UPDATE**: I don't know what I change, but it works now. I apologize for intruding on everyone's time. Thank you for helping me look into this though.

Comment: Just to be sure: `you'llneverknow` is just a replacement for this question? Are there any non-ASCII characters in the real bot token?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Are you saying there non-ASCII characters in you'llneverknow?

Comment: @BillWoodger No, that's fine. But if it's an replacement, the real token might contain non-ASCII chars.

Comment: @abcde13 Can you show the code which takes the snapshot?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Thanks, understand now.

Comment: Does it work if you run directly (target/debug/appname) instead of cargo run?

Comment: Do you run you project in the terminal where this is set?

Did you try to run it like `DISCORD_TOKEN=yourtoken cargo run`?

Comment: *none of the `CARGO` variables exist, but they are printed in the Rust code* — That's because `cargo run` sets them.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt That's just a replacement string. But the real string is all ASCII characters.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson You are right. It does work if I run it from target/debug/appname

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I've run it in the terminal where, just before, I source my bashrc and grep to make sure that environment variable exists.

Comment: `echo 'fn main() { println!("{:?}", ::std::env::var("FOO")); }' > src/main.rs && FOO=bar cargo run` results in `Ok("bar")`. Cargo shouldn't be removing any environment variables.

Comment: @Shepmaster your code returned `Ok("bar")`. So how does that reflect what I should do in my code? And why does running the actual executable in the target dir work?

Comment: @abcde13 are you saying that if you use your environment variable with my code, suitably modified, you get the value of your key? You really need to produce a [mcve] to narrow down your problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes. If I run your code as main.rs with `"DISCORD_TOKEN"`  as the key and remove the part FOO=bar, it gets the token. And I concur. I will get a testcase up in a sec.

Comment: And I don't know what happened. I reran it just now, and it worked. Opened and closed the terminal, and it still worked.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time. Gonna upvote you all for helping regardless.

Comment: I think it is better to delete this question because there was not a real problem, so it will not be helpful for others who read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undeleted this question because I got the answer. But it's because I didn't examine all the factors before asking the question.

It worked when I ran `cargo run`, but didn't work when I ran `sudo cargo run`.  I was running it in sudo because I was trying to read memory of another process. The `sudo` profile has it's own set of env vars, and it resets the environment before going sudo.

To fix this, I ran `sudo visudo` and inserted this line

`Defaults env_keep += "DISCORD_TOKEN'`

From there, it worked.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) got me the answer.

Comment: You could also call sudo with the `-E` parameter to "transfer" environment variables to the sudo profile.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was long ago, but in case someone is struggling with it:

In my case it was because my shell was `Fish` and my variable was defined in `Bash`.

I've presumed Rust `env::var()` reads whatever it finds without matter where.

So in my Fish:

```
set -x MY_VAR "value"
```

Or in Bash:

```
export MY_VAR="value"
```