# Travis-ci needs root privilege when using go test, how to set it?

Tags: go, travis-ci

I have Go test file and it needs root privilege to run it (go test). How to set it in Travis ci?

Here is yml:

```
language: go
sudo: required
go:
   - tip
notifications:
  email:
     on_success: change
     on_failure: always
```

After git push, travis-ci build failing with default configure.

Comment: Why would your test need root?

Comment: my program  is about icmp ,  c, err := net.Dial("ip4:icmp", address) , so when go test  need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In travis you can use `sudo` so if you want to run your tests with root permission, change the script section:

```
script: sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" go test ./...
```

Or if you are using a Makefile:

```
script: sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" make
```

Comment: en ... ，  i have done it  . but  it says :   go not found  if use sudo go test ,  and go test  well use.  so   how to set   in travis  and  i can find go command    with sudo .

Comment: Try with -E https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot ^.^, finally , i use sudo - E env "PATH=$PATH" go test and can run it

Answer (score -2):

`script:
  - sudo env "PATH=$PATH" npm test`