# How to add environmental variables in AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am writing an application in Java and I need to use environmental variables in AWS EC2 machine (Linux). I am using `System.getenv("myvariable")` in the application to get the particular environment variable. I need to  set the permanent environmental variables and currently I have set the variable in `~/.bashrc` , `~/.profile` and also `~/.bash_profile`. 
I am giving **`export myvariable=xyz`** in al the 3 files and then I ran **`source ~/.bashrc`** , **`source ~/.profile`** and **`source ~/.bash_profile`**. However I am getting null in the application.

I still don't understand why I am not able to get any environmental variables even though I am exporting the variable in `~/.bash_profile`.I have even checked by running  **`echo $myvariable`** and I can see **xyz**.

If I set the same environment variable in my local MAC machine in the same way I set above and use the same shell to run the same java code, I can see the variable with the value.

So basically I am getting null every time in my AWS EC2 linux machine.

Is there any other place I need to set the variable? I have even restarted the machine but it didn't help.

Comment: It sounds like your Java application isn't running as the same user so it isn't getting the same environment variables. How do you run the Java application?

Comment: I am using spring-boot to run my maven application. So I issue this command sudo  ./mvnw spring-boot:run to run my application .

Comment: By default, `sudo` doesn't preserve environment variables, so when you're running your application via `sudo`, all the environment variables you need will not be available to the application. Any particular reason why your service needs to be run as `sudo`? Port privileges?

Comment: As my application create a target folder and needs permission to create .class files in the target folder during the runtime. So is there any way we can make those environmental variables available in sudo?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. I just used sudo -E /mvnw spring-boot:run and I am  able to see the value for environmental variable. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is how you are setting the env variables. Sudo does not preserve them by default, so you need to use the `sudo -E` option.

This is explained in more detail in: [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)