# Environment variables missing when executing via pkexec

Tags: python, linux

If I execute `print os.environ` without pkexec I get lots of useful system environment variables, however, once I execute with, most of them are gone. How can I get them back with using pkexec? I understand there's a workaround using sudo but haven't found one yet for pkexec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

Comment: The `man` page says `-E, --preserve-env
                 Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to pre‐
                 serve their existing environment variables.  The security
                 policy may return an error if the user does not have permis‐
                 sion to preserve the environment.`

Comment: @JoshLee - that's a good reference answer. Would you like to close this as a dup?

Comment: Wait I will edit my question. It's different alright

Comment: I don't want to go and modify the sudoers file because I'd preferably like a general solution that works on different linux machines

Comment: [pkexec doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) says: 
`The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms.`. `pkexec` is a policykit thing... I have no idea if you can add env to policies. You may have luck asking this question on serverfault.com.

Comment: @tselaney this is not a dup sudo != pkexec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't. From the [`pkexec` man page](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=pkexec&ampsect=1):

> The environment that PROGRAM will run in will be set to a minimal known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking pkexec.

You can cause `pkexec` to retain some environmental variables (i.e. to allow X11 programs to work by retaining `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`) using the `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui` annotation. However, retaining all of the environmental variables appears to be a deliberate rejected decision.

Comment: BTW, if interesting to anyone, I use `pkexec`ed app that need UI access like this: `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY WAYLAND_DISPLAY=$WAYLAND_DISPLAY XDG_SESSION_TYPE=$XDG_SESSION_TYPE XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR myapp`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to keep a few environment variables, you can always preserve them using `env`:

```
pkexec bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin

pkexec env PATH=$PATH bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```