# Docker-compose not passing environment variable to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56 with docker-compose 1.12.0, build b31ff33 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I simply want to pass an environment variable and display it from my script running in a container. I am doing this according to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment . The problem is that the variable is not passed to the container.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
env-file-test:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    - DEMO_VAR
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
COPY docker-start.sh /
CMD ["/docker-start.sh"]
```

And the `docker-start.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "DEMO_VAR Var Passed in: $DEMO_VAR"
```

I try to set the variable in my current terminal session and pass it to the container:

```
$ export DEMO_VAR=aabbdd
$ echo $DEMO_VAR
aabbdd
$ sudo docker-compose up
Starting envfiletest_env-file-test_1
Attaching to envfiletest_env-file-test_1
env-file-test_1  | DEMO_VAR Var Passed in: 
envfiletest_env-file-test_1 exited with code 0
```

So you can see that the variable DEMO_VAR is empty!

I also tried using variables in docker-compose.yml like this: `DEMO_VAR=${DEMO_VAR}` but then when I run `sudo docker-compose up`, I get a warning: "WARNING: The DEMO_VAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.".

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to pass the variable to the container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution. Answering my own question...

The problem was with the `sudo` command. It turned out that it does not pass environment variables by default. There are some possible solutions:

1. Use `sudo -E`. Demo:

   ```
   $ export DEMO_VAR=aabbdd
   $ echo $DEMO_VAR
   aabbdd
   $ sudo -E docker-compose up
   env-file-test_1  | DEMO_VAR Var Passed in: aabbdd
   ```
2. Use `sudo VAR=value`:

   ```
   sudo DEMO_VAR=$DEMO_VAR docker-compose up
   ```
3. Add environment variables to the sudoers file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636711)
4. Use docker without sudo (https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

Answer (score -2):

you should use  `ENV` in your Dockerfile, and avoid export.

See the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: Could you give an example how to use `ENV` to pass the environment variable from the current terminal?

Comment: You use ENV in your Dockerfile, with a line such as `ENV demo_var aabbdd` or other syntax `ENV demo_var=aabbdd`

Comment: But I don't want to set the value in the Dockerfile. The `DEMO_VAR` is only an example, but in a real-world project it can contain a server-specific configuration variable or even a password. I want to pass it from the current session (current terminal).

Comment: "The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time"... but I want to pass a variable at run-time, not build-time. BTW: I've just found a solution to my problem. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: at run time, you have `docker run -e` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables