# Running electron as root on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, electron, root, sudo

I am making an application with electron which uses the wiring-pi library. This needs access to the GPIO on my Raspberry Pi, which requires root.

When I run `electron .` in the folder, the app opens fine but then says (in the terminal):

`wiringPiSetup: Must be root. (Did you forget sudo?)`

However when I try `sudo electron .`, I get an error:

`sudo: electron: command not found`

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Also, for the record, the same thing happens when I run npm as root:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rubiks-robot $ sudo npm
sudo: npm: command not found
```

Any ideas of how I can fix this issue and run Electron as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like a problem of environment variables. The environmnet variables are set for your user but not for root.

Try to ship your variables with the "-E" switch of the sudo command:

sudo -E command

Please try to see here for other similar questions

[How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)