# Why is GOPATH not recognized by google-cloud-sdk go-app-stager?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go

When I try to update my appengine project, it gives me an error.

```
$ sudo gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Staging command [/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/bin/go-app-stager /Users/baz/app/app.yaml /tmp/tmpSZLK/tmpIQ4] failed with return code [1].

------------------------------------ STDOUT ------------------------------------
------------------------------------ STDERR ------------------------------------
2017/07/08 16:22:06 failed analyzing /Users/baz/app: cannot find package "bitbucket.org/foo/bar" in any of:
    ($GOROOT not set)
    ($GOPATH not set)
GOPATH: 

$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/baz/go
$ go env GOPATH
/Users/baz/go
```

Clearly GOPATH is set (I export it in my .bash_profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Do not use `sudo` for deploying the app.

### Longer version

You're running the [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command using `sudo`. `sudo` by the nature of the command will not retain the current set of environment variables when running the command as `root` user.

Try deploying your app engine app without `sudo`:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

If you do need to run you command as `sudo` (which is a smell that your setup is broken somehow), you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo). Although, I would recommend looking into the possibility of running your command without `sudo`.