# python execute multiple command subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a command like

```
command = "su - user; cd $CONFIG; grep domain domains.xml"
```

And need to execute the commands one after other and capture the output of grep.

```
    def subprocess_cmd(command):
        fnlogs("comand = " + command)
        process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
        fnlogs("proc_stdout = " +proc_stdout + "\n")

subprocess_cmd('su - user; cd $CONFIG; grep domain domains.xml')
```

Output says grep: domains.xml: No such file or directory, although the file exists its not able to find it.

Comment: you should verify the output of `pwd` to see that your subprocess is in the same directory.

Comment: i'm doing a cd $CONFIG which is having domains.xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not passing a value for `CONFIG`.

If you know the intended value within the script, you can do

```
d = dict(os.environ)
d["CONFIG"] = "/some/directory"
process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, env=d)
```

You might also have to call `sudo` with `-E` to preserve the environment that you pass to the first outermost `shell` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/693140).

On a more general note, you subcommand does not seem to do anything that you could not achieve within Python without relying on external commands. I would recommend to reconsider your approach altogether, and just open the file and extract the respective text from the string (eg using regular expressions).

Comment: What approach you suggest?  the commands will be stored in a file and then executed?

Comment: Thank you @Stefan i managed to get is solved by writing output to file and split on result.