# Python can't read the environment variable

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I used Ubuntu16.04

When I use `sudo python3` into the interactive shell

```
import os
os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

it can't read the SECRET_KEY

I set it in the /etc/profile.d/project.sh

project.sh

```
export SECRET_KEY=the_key
```

After reloading it but in vain.

I　also set in the ~/.profile

But still got the error.

How do I fixed it?

[*EDIT*]

It can work in `sudo -E python3`

But the futher problem is that when I run `sudo  -E supervisor reread/reload`

I have the command defined in the [program:site] section to launch the gunicorn.conf.py

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf

```
[program:site]
directory=/home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station
command=/home/nhcc/venv/weather_station/bin/gunicorn -c /home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station/gunicorn.conf.py -p gunicorn.pod weather_station.wsgi
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# /usr/bin/python3
import os

bind = "{}:8080".format(os.environ['DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST'])
worders = (os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN') * 2) + 1
loglevel = 'error'
command = "WTR_VENV/gunicorn"
pythonpath = "$PROJECT/weather_station"
```

it will showed up the error .

Comment: Sanity check: what do you see if you do `echo $SECRET_KEY` on the command line?

Comment: it can showed  successfully,also in `python3`shell

Comment: And if you [use the `-E` flag to sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo), does it work?

Comment: Matt Gibson `sudo -E bash -c 'echo SECRET_KEY'` it can work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run it with `sudo`, you're actually going to run the program as `root`. So any environment setup for your current user isn't going to apply unfortunately without special care.

Fortunately `sudo -E` will do the trick. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) for more details.

Comment: thanks,but actually I have a futher question in the above edit

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question then. Piggybacking on an answered question is not a good thing and is against the "rules" as it were.

Comment: ok I just explain that I actually not ask the dubpilicated questioin