# Not able to start Informix server

Tags: informix

I am new to Informix. I installed Informix in the folder - `/opt/Informix_Software_Bundle.`

I am using the following command to start Informix server.

`cd /opt/Informix_Software_Bundle
 sudo ./oninit -i`

And I am getting the following error message.

`Unable to read $INFORMIXDIR (/usr/informix).`

So I tried to set the environment variable `INFORMIXDIR` in `~/.profile` as given below:

`export INFORMIXDIR="/opt/Informix_Software_Bundle"`

I also tried the following command:

`INFORMIXDIR=/opt/Informix_Software_Bundle;export INFORMIXDIR`

I tried logging out and in again. But nothing helped.

I will greatly appreciate if somebody can help me with this. Thanks for reading.

```
System - Mac OS Sierra
Informix version - 12.10
```

Comment: When you run `sudo`, does it clear the environment for you — unset INFORMIXDIR? I create a script that sets the environment precisely as I want it, and then run that.  In context; it would be `sudo $HOME/bin/osiris_19.start` (where I keep the script in my personal `bin` directory, and use `servername.start` for the start script for the given server). I run Informix 12.10 on a Mac (macOS High Sierra 10.13 these days, but previously on Sierra 10.12) without problems.  But I have an environment setting script, and I cheat and don't use `sudo` (but I do use root privileges when starting Informix).

Comment: Thanks for the help. sudo was resetting my environment variables. So I used sudo -E option to start it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of environment variables used by the Informix server which include:

- INFORMIXDIR : points to the directory where the product is installed. Add $INFORMIXDIR/bin to $PATH.
- ONCONFIG : indicates the name of the main server configuration file in $INFORMIXDIR/etc. If not specified this will default to "onconfig."
- INFORMIXSERVER : indicates the name of the Informix instance to connect to and refers to the DBSERVERNAME or a DBSERVERALIAS entry in the onconfig file referenced by $ONCONFIG.
- INFORMIXSQLHOSTS : indicates the full path name of the communications configuration file used by Informix clients and servers. This will include an entry for the name specified by $INFORMIXSERVER. If this environment variable is not specified it defaults to $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts.

Just having some or all of these environment variables set is not sufficient for starting an Informix server from scratch. There are setup tasks such as editing the onconfig file to specify the location of the root chunk - this is the initial location where the server stores its data. For more details you might like to refer to the Informix online documentation:

- [Getting started with IBM Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.po.doc/getstart.htm)
- [Overview of database server configuration and administration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0007.htm)

One of the most straightforward ways to get started is to use the demonstration server instance that may be created during installation. I'm not directly familiar with the Mac OS installation but for all other platforms the Informix installation process includes an option to configure and initialize a demonstration server, and I suspect Mac OS will be the same. This will create an environment file in $INFORMIXDIR which will include settings for the variables named above.

One word of caution: the oninit command is used to both start the Informix server and initialize the chunks where the data is stored. The -i argument will perform the complete disk initialization which is precisely what you want for the first time the Informix server is started. On subsequent restarts you would not normally use this argument or else all the data stored by the server may be lost.

Answer (score 0):

As sudo by default resets environment variables it is usual to have

A) A script to set the required environment variables for a given server.

B) Another wrapper script to start/stop the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Sudo.
Check this post [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) for various options to preserver environment variables while doing sudo.

However, I would like to ask "Do you really have to do sudo to start informix?" AFAIK you need to create Informix user and Group. Start informix using `oninit -v` (-v for verbose option) with the environment variables mentioned above.

Also, be careful with the `oninit -i` option and never use it on the database that is already configured and has data.