# docker-compose does not see a host environment variable set in /var/profile.d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here below is a snippet of my `docker-compose.yaml` where I try to pass an environment variable (i.e. `$GOPATH`) to my `Dockerfile`:

```
kontrol:
  container_name: 'kontrol'
  build:
    context: '.'
    dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    args:
      gopath: '${GOPATH}'
  volumes:
    - '/certs:${HOME}/.kite/certs'
  ports:
    - '6000:6000'
  depends_on:
    - 'etcd'
```

And here is the actual `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM scratch
ARG gopath
ADD ${gopath}/bin/kontrol /
ENV KONTROL_PORT=6000 \
    KONTROL_USERNAME="gonzo" \
    KONTROL_STORAGE="etcd" \
    KONTROL_MACHINES="http://etcd:2379" \
    KONTROL_KONTROLURL="http://kontrol:6000/kite" \
    KONTROL_PUBLICKEYFILE="/certs/key_pub.pem" \
    KONTROL_PRIVATEKEYFILE="/certs/key.pem" \
    KITE_ENVIRONMENT="dev" \
    KITE_REGION="ch"
CMD [ "/kontrol -initial", "/kontrol" ]
```

The problem is that even if `GOPATH` is defined in my current shell...

```
[j3d@pc-5]$ echo $GOPATH
/home/j3d/Projects/go
```

... docker-compose doesn't see it:

```
[j3d@pc-5 test]$ sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
WARNING: The GOPATH variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
...
```

Strangely, environment variable `HOME` is visible and does work. The only difference between those environment variables is that `GOPATH` is set in `/etc/profile.d/go.sh`:

```
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOROOT/bin"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute docker-compose with `sudo`. Your variable is not set, most probably, because the environment variables are not kept when using sudo [How to keep environment variables using `sudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

Comment: Use sudo's `-E` switch to preserve env variables.

Comment: Or you could use docker without sudo. https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thank u very much:-)

Comment: @b0gusb only if you understand the consequences.