# /usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 181: 10208 Killed, Browser gets closed as XvFb process gets killed by itself

Tags: linux, centos7, xvfb

Running my automation suite with following command

/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn -e clean install -gs ~/.m2/settings.xml test -Dsuite=checktest -Dbrowser=firefox -Dplatform=linux

However browser gets opened but closed after few seconds, and command line errors are following:

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 181: 10208 Killed DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1
```

Line 181 from xvfb-run file: DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1

Settings that are done for xvfb on my machine are:

```
export DISPLAY=:99

nohup Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1920x1920x24 &
```

ps -ef |grep Xvfb shows that xvfb process is running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/608639)

Answer (score 0):

removing -S switch has worked. sudo -s runs a shell with root privileges

/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/maven/bin/mvn -e clean install -gs ~/.m2/settings.xml test -Dsuite=checktest -Dbrowser=firefox -Dplatform=linux

Comment: Again faced the same issue, Can anyone please help on that.