# How to pick a proper version of Python in virtual ebvironment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, virtualenv

I create a virtual environment and run PySpark script. If I do these steps on MacOS, everything works fine. However, if I run them on Linux (Ubuntu 16), then the incorrect version of Python is picked. Of course, I previously did `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` on Linux, but still the same issue. Below I explain all steps:

```
1. edit profile :vim ~/.profile

2. add the code into the file: export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

3. execute command:  source ~/.profile
```

Then I do:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install virtualenv
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.0/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
tar -xvzf spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz && rm spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

virtualenv tes-ve 
source test-ve/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If I execute `python --version` inside the visual environment, I see `Python 3.5.2`.

However when I run Spark code with this command: `sudo /usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit mySpark.py`, I get `Using Python version 2.7...` for these lines of code:

```
print("Using Python version %s (%s, %s)" % (
    platform.python_version(),
    platform.python_build()[0],
    platform.python_build()[1]))
```

Comment: Please be reminded that `sudo` clears all environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PYSPARK_PYTHON` sets the call that's used to execute Python on the slave nodes. There's a separate environment variable called `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` that sets the call for the driver node (ie the node on which your script is initially run). So you need to set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3` too.

### Edit

As phd points out, you may be running into trouble with your environment since you're using `sudo` to call the Pyspark submit. One thing to try would be using `sudo -E` instead of just `sudo`. The `-E` option will [preserve your environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/425458) (though it isn't perfect).

If that fails, you can try setting the `spark.pyspark.driver.python` and `spark.pyspark.python` options directly. For example, you can pass the desired values into your call to `spark-submit`:

```
sudo /usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=python3 --conf spark.pyspark.python=python3 mySpark.py
```

There's a bunch of different ways to set these options (see [this doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for full details). If one doesn't work/is inconvenient for you, try another.

Comment: No, I still see `Using Python version 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018 14:36:49)`. Should I run export commands inside the virtual environment, right?

Comment: I added some alternative fixes to my answer that you can try