# Run some commands as one user, and access variables set by another user

Tags: linux, bash, multiline, ubuntu-18.04

**What I'm aiming for:**

I want to run:

1. multiple lines at once
2. under another user
3. with access to the variables set by the user I'm running from

So from this:

```
ROOT_VAR='var-set-from-root'

cmd="
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
"
```

the DESIRED RESULT would be:

```
var-set-from-root
UserA
/home/UserA
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1 run with bash; commands contained in double quotes:

```
cmd="
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
"

sudo -u UserA bash -c "{$cmd}"

# result (has access to root var but still running as root):
var-set-from-root
root
/root
```

2 run with bash with commands in heredoc

```
sudo -u UserA bash -c<<EOF
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
EOF

# result (error):
bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

3 run with su and commands in heredoc with single quote

```
su UserA <<'EOF'
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
EOF

# result (no access to root var but running as correct user):

UserA
/home/UserA
```

4 run with su and commands in heredoc without quotes

```
su UserA <<EOF
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
EOF

# result (has access to root var but still running as root):
var-set-from-root
root
/root
```

5 run with bash; commands in double quotes; root var passed as param:

```
cmd="
 echo $1
 echo `whoami`
 echo $HOME
"

sudo -u UserA bash -c "{$cmd}" $ROOT_VAR

# result (no access to root variable parameter):

root
/root
```

None of them can access the variable set from the root user while at the same time running under the non-root user.  Is it possible even by using parameters?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/589259) help?

Comment: Your first example actually works under Ubuntu 18.04. I tried this under root and it worked: `whoami && TEST="1" && sudo -u nav bash -c "echo $TEST && whoami && echo $HOME"`

Output is `root 1 nav /home/nav`

Comment: @TheNavigat strange....I copy/paste/modify-user/run your command under root and output is: `root
1
UserA
/root`  If I `su UserA` and `echo $HOME` I get `/home/UserA`  This is in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Yep, you're correct. My bad. This fixes it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177011/215614. It's basically because of a couple of things: you need `-i` to include the user's environment, and `\$HOME` to ensure that the dollar sign actually passes on to the command correctly instead of passing on root's own HOME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight modification of your first example should work:

```
cmd="
 echo $ROOT_VAR
 echo \`whoami\`
 echo \$HOME
"

sudo -H -u UserA bash -c "{$cmd}"
```

`-H` is needed to set the `$HOME` variable of the user [based on this](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html#H).

Regarding the backslashes, the distinction here between `\$HOME` and `$ROOT_VAR` is quite tricky. When the command is parsed, `$ROOT_VAR` is actually expanded to it's real value. In other words, the value of `cmd` is the following:

```
cmd="
  echo var-set-from-root
  echo `whoami`
  echo $HOME
"
```

You need to use backslashes to avoid parsing of `whoami` and `$HOME` in the root's environment and instead pass on the execution of the command to the user's bash itself.

Comment: Did the sample in the first section run for you without errors?  I get this: `mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/0: Permission denied
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
`

Comment: I wasn't able to get `-i` to work, as mentioned in my first comment.  But this did output my desired result: `sudo -H -u zteed998 bash -c "{$cmd}"` So if you update your answer accordingly, I will accept your answer.

Comment: My bad. It looks like because of the way `-i` works, the commands have to be joined using `&&` or so in order to work. I didn't test it properly. `-H` works and is actually more specific than `-i`, so I modified the answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: It really solve my issue. Please note command (cmd here) should be use like this only because it didn't work for single line. Also, avoid using su command.

Answer (score 2):

```
# as root
var=1
export var
sudo -E -u kamil sh -c 'echo "$(whoami) var = $var"'
echo "$(whoami) var = $var"
```

will output:

```
kamil var = 1
root var = 1
```

1. sudo let's you run as another user
2. sueo -E allows to preserve environment, see man sudo
3. After sudoing, you need to execute a program - typically `sh` or `bash` for a script, sometimes with `<<'EOF'` for unexpanded multiline commands

The folllwing:

```
export var=1
sudo -E -u kamil sh <<'EOF'
echo "I am $(whoami) and..."
echo "var = $var"
echo "Let's change it!"
var=2
echo "var = $var"
EOF
echo "$(whoami) var = $var"
```

will output:

```
I am kamil and...
var = 1
Let's change it!
var = 2
root var = 1
```

You can always be even more explicit with `env`:

```
sudo -u kamil env var="$var" sh -c 'echo "$var"'
```

where you exactly choose what you pass around.

Comment: This had the same issue that @TheNavigat answer had, which is that `$HOME` was outputting `/root`.  With the `-H` switch, it outputs correctly as `/home/UserA`