# dotenv doesn't work with root priviledges

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, dotenv

I'm running a node app created with `create-react-app`. I wanted to make it run on port `80`, so I added a `.env` file with the contents

```
PORT=80
```

When I run `npm start`, I get

```
? Admin permissions are required to run a server on a port below 1024.
```

but when I run `sudo npm start`, the app starts on port `3000`.

Why does my `.env` file get ignored when I run with `sudo`, and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:** This question is not about how to keep my current environment variables when I run `sudo`. This question is about the behavior of `.env`, and why it doesn't work when running with `sudo`.

Interestingly, when I use su, eg.

```sh
$ su
# npm start
```

It runs on port 80.

To be entirely clear, I would like to know how I can run my app on port `80` without passing the port in the command, i.e. `sudo PORT=80 npm start`.
I believe this is the whole point of `.env`, hence the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) Have a look at this one.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman This is related, but I want to know about the behavior of dotenv, because I would have expected node to insert `PORT=80` into whatever environment I end up in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run a server on port 80 without root permissions, but I think you can redirect connections from port 80 to other ports.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: This is useful, thank you, but not quite what I'm looking for. I don't mind running it as root, I just want to do it without passing the port eg. `sudo PORT=80 npm start`.