# Why doesn't "go get" install the package to GOPATH?

Tags: go

When I use go get command:

```
sudo go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
```

My GOPATH is:

```
GOPATH="/home/hadoop/gopath"
```

and i found go get will create a new directory which named "go" in /home,and the dep package is in it, I want to know why not in GOPATH but to create a new directory?

Comment: what happens when you run it without sudo?

Comment: try without `sudo`

Comment: sorry to comment late,I have understand why this happened, thank you all very much

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using sudo, the environment variables are not the same as the ones you see as yourself (your user).

You can, for example, use: 
`sudo --preserve-env go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep` but likely you will have problems with permissions and whatnot.

Better idea would be to just run go get without sudo - if the `GOPATH` is in your home directory I don't see a point to use sudo in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this
[How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

So I believe the env is not set when you use sudo.

You can check GOPATH's value using this `go env` and `sudo go env`

Answer (score -2):

I have finished, if we do not use sudo , it will download to GOPATH, though I don't know why

Comment: because sudo runs as root and not as the user and because of that different env variables are used