# Issue with perl regex search and replace with environment variable

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu

I'm running a GCE VM with Ubuntu 18, and having an issue with a perl command.

```
export ip_addr=`hostname -i`
echo "set \$ip_addr_priv \"{my_ip_address}\"" | sudo perl -n -e 's/(\$ip_addr_priv) +"\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}"/\1 "$ENV{ip_addr}"/g; print;'
```

When I run this in the command line, I get the following output:

```
set $ip_addr_priv ""
```

Instead of something like this:

```
set $ip_addr_priv "127.0.0.1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the environment variable is not exported into the `sudo` environment? See also [How to keep environment variables when using sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/2173773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (and by design), `sudo` doesn't pass the current user's environment on to the new process.

You can override this behaviour with the `-E` command line flag.

```
echo "set \$ip_addr_priv \"{my_ip_address}\"" | sudo perl -n -e 's/(\$ip_addr_priv) +"\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}"/\1 "$ENV{ip_addr}"/g; print;'
set $ip_addr_priv ""
```

Vs:

```
echo "set \$ip_addr_priv \"{my_ip_address}\"" | sudo -E perl -n -e 's/(\$ip_addr_priv) +"\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}"/\1 "$ENV{ip_addr}"/g; print;'
set $ip_addr_priv "127.0.1.1"
```