# The environment variable AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID must be set

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am using Linux 18.04 and I want to lunch a spark cluster on EC2.

I used the export command to set environment variables

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MyAccesskey
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=Mysecretkey
```

but when I run the command to lunch the spark cluster I get

> ERROR: The environment variable AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID must be set

I put all the commands I used in case I made a mistake:

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/keypair.pem   /usr/local/spark/keypair.pem
sudo mv ~/Downloads/credentials.csv   /usr/local/spark/credentials.csv
# Make sure the .pem file is readable by the current user.
chmod 400 "keypair.pem"
# Go into the spark directory and set the environment variables with the credentials information
cd spark
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SECRET_KEY
# To install Spark 2.0 on the cluster:
sudo spark-ec2/spark-ec2 -k keypair --identity-file=keypair.pem --region=us-west-2 --zone=us-west-2a --copy-aws-credentials --instance-type t2.micro --worker-instances 1 launch project-launch
```

I am new to these things and any help is really appreciated

Comment: You've set the AWS environment variables in your current environment but then started a new environment using `sudo`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Comment: Do you have ~/.aws/credentials file?

Comment: After exporting vars you should source bashrc.

Comment: @marxmacher Yes  I have that file
You mean just writing  source bashrc.  ?

Comment: source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables can be simply passed after `sudo` in form ENV=VALUE and they'll be accepted by followed command. It's not known to me if there are restrictions to this usage, so my example problem can be solved with:

```
sudo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SECRET_KEY spark-ec2/spark-ec2 -k keypair --identity-file=keypair.pem --region=us-west-2 --zone=us-west-2a --copy-aws-credentials --instance-type t2.micro --worker-instances 1 launch project-launch
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also retrieve the value AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY by using the get subcommand for `aws configure`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id)
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key)
```

In command line:

```
sudo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id) AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key) spark-ec2/spark-ec2 -k keypair --identity-file=keypair.pem --region=us-west-2 --zone=us-west-2a --copy-aws-credentials --instance-type t2.micro --worker-instances 1 launch project-launch
```

source: [AWS Command Line Interface User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)