# Ubuntu -- Nautilus scripts won't run "srm" to securely wipe file

Tags: linux, bash, nautilus

I'm trying to add a context menu option to Nautilus so that when I right click on a file, I can choose to run *srm* to securely overwrite it with zeros instead of moving it to /Trash or *rm*'ing it. I have the following executable in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

#Make local Nautilus filepath variable global
export srmthis=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

#Copy the above variable to a log
echo "$srmthis" >> logfile.txt

#Now, please srm secure-delete the file indicated in the filepath
sudo -E /usr/bin/srm -flz "$srmthis"
```

*$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS* is a variable set by Nautilus when a file is selected within it. My thinking is that I'd grab that into my own variable *$srmthis* and then pass it to *srm* as its target file with options *"-flz"* for a faster, albeit more insecure wipe.

But it doesn't work. No output, no popup warning.

When I `echo "$filetosrm" >> somefile.txt` I do get an output so I know the variable is set. I can also use *srm* by itself in the terminal no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

P.S. Tried running srm with gksu, pkexec, | xargs, etc to no avail.

Comment: does it run without sudo? then export filetosrm=...

Comment: No @alecxs , sadly it does not.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/57915
https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Here's the new code that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Make local Nautilus filepath variable global
srmthis=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

#Copy the above variable to a log
echo "$srmthis" >> srmtemp.txt

#Get the first line from temp file to get rid of annoying newline
line=$(head -n1 srmtemp.txt)

#Wipe the file with srm: -fllz fast mode, -r recursively for any subdirectories
/usr/bin/srm -fllzr "$line"

#Clean up
/usr/bin/srm -l srmtemp.txt
```

Also, instead of using `sudo /usr/bin/srm` I ended up adding `srm` to my `/etc/sudoers` for my username with `whiterabbit ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/srm` which allowed it to run without having to have the command `sudo` in the script.

This adds **srm** as a Nautilus script. I can now rightclick on a file and then go to *Scripts -> SRM* and wipe-delete the file with zeros right in the GUI instead of rm'ing it or moving it to trash.