# Why does git needs sudo privileges to clone and if so, writes to root directory?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to clone a repository but this error shows up:

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
Cloning Oh My Zsh...
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/usr/share/oh-my-zsh': Permission denied
Error: git clone of oh-my-zsh repo failed
```

If I use sudo before the previous command it writes to the root directory as you can see:

```
$ sudo sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
The $ZSH folder already exists (/root/.oh-my-zsh).
You'll need to remove it if you want to reinstall.
```

What's to be done to solve this? I know that `git clone` should write to the current directory, but it doesn't! Why?

Comment: This is not Git, this is the install.sh script you're running. It's given you instructions on how to fix the issue. Be wary of running scripts you don't understand, *especially* as root. This one is trying to install its configuration file (.oh-my-zsh) in root's home folder, not yours.

Comment: I am not running as root, and yes I have installed this package a dozen times on other machines so I am sure what I am installing.

Comment: `sudo` executes the command as root.

Comment: Did you have the ZSH environment variable set when you ran it the first time?

Comment: No I did not, It does it automaticaly. And yes I know that sudo=superuser do, but that does not change the install directory to root also. That's what happens to me. That's what I was trying to explain.

Comment: I think it's clear that the error says: `Error: git clone of oh-my-zsh repo failed`, because it has to clone it first then run the install. It gives me the same error with every other repo I'm trying to clone: `git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/usr/share/oh-my-zsh//custom/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions': Permission denied`

Comment: It seems to me that my user does not have some permission that it needs in order to write to that directory.

Comment: You told it to clone into `$ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions` which means $ZSH_CUSTOM is set to `/usr/share/oh-my-zsh//custom`. You don't have permission to write to `/usr/share/`, this is normal.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I got that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Git, this is [the install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh) for [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh).

install.sh is trying to clone a repository. Where it installs is controlled by the ZSH environment variable. By default it will install into `~/.oh-my-zsh`. If it went into /usr/share/oh-my-zsh you had ZSH set to that. You don't have permission to write to /usr/share. This is normal, a regular user should not have /usr/share permission.

When run with `sudo` (ie. with root permissions) it does have permission to write to `/usr/share/oh-my-zsh`, but `sudo` will clean up your environment variables so ZSH was not set for the command. It ran with its default `~/.oh-my-zsh`. Normally sudo should preserve your home directory, but somehow it isn't and it's gone into root's home directory.

---

How to "fix" this depends on what you want. First, check what's in your environment with `env | sort` and make sure it's all correct.

If you just want to install the software for yourself, `unset ZSH` and run the installer. It will go into ~/oh-my-zsh.

If you want to install the software for everyone, download the script, use `sudo` and [make setting ZSH part of the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33183620/14660).

```
cd /tmp
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh
sudo ZSH=/usr/share/oh-my-sh sh -c install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. It's all good. Like you said, my $ZSH variable was the problem.

Comment: And the fact that I was such a noob back then! :facepalm