# how can use local env variable in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

how can i access to my os env variable in docker compose?

in my os:

```sh
export TOKEN=""
sudo docker-compose up
# WARNING: The TOKEN variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
    environment:
       - TOKEN=$TOKEN
```

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: Does running `sudo -E docker-compose up` help?  `sudo` normally discards environment variables, but see [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```sh
export ENV_VARIABLE=""
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
    environment:
       - ENV_VARIABLE=$ENV_VARIABLE
```

your mistake was in using sudo !

just  `run docker-compose up`

Comment: Since you could specify `volumes: [/:/host], user: root` in the Compose configuration to get read-write access to the entire host filesystem, it's very reasonable to require `sudo` to use Docker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks about right, environment variables you export in your shell for the compose process to be able to grab should be available to it. If you're having issues maybe changing one of the names would suffice?

I'm linking a [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-not-seeing-environment-variables-on-the-host/11837) from the docker forums on the issue