# Setting Docker environment variables in Azure DevOps using bash task

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I am having a problem setting up an environment variable as part of Releasing my container. in Azure DevOps, I have a bash task in which I am trying to set an environment variable (CUSER)

```
export CUSER=$(CUSER) && \
echo $(MYPASS) | sudo -S docker run \
-e CUSER \
--name $(CNAME) \
-p 80:80 $(INAME):$(Build.BuildId) &
```

The container runs but the environment variable is not set. But it is set when I execute the script directly on the host like `export CUSER="Dev9" && docker run -e CUSER --name demo1 -p 80:80 myimage:256`
I suspect there is a problem with the way my command is formatted but I am not sure where or what.

Comment: You are using `sudo`. To avoid vulnerabilities, it doesn't preserve the environment variables when running things as root. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by changing how I authenticate sudo.

```
sudo -S <<< $(MYPASS) echo export CUSER=$(CUSER) && \
docker run -e CUSER \
--name $(CNAME) \
-p 80:80 $(INAME):$(Build.BuildId) &
```