# Python subprocess.Popen pass modified environment to use new environment varibels in postinst script

Tags: python, environment-variables, subprocess, dpkg, post-install

I have a server to install different debian packages that contain a `postinst` script.

Some packages require a modified environment containing some ports to connect to.

When I call the server to install the package, I pass in the request an object parameter `vars` containing the custom ports:
`{'vars': {'CUSTOM_PORT_1': '7755', 'CUSTOM_PORT_2': '7766'}}`

In my code I call `subprocess.Popen` to run a command that will install the debian package. Here's my code:

```
def open_process(command, app_vars=None):
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    if app_vars:
        my_env.update(app_vars)

    p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'dpkg', '-i', 'path-to-package'], env=my_env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    
    output, err = p.communicate()
    return_code = p.returncode
    return output, err, return_code
```

I expected that the modified environment will be passed to the `postinst` script, via `env=my_env` so I can print them out. The `postinst` script runs an app that uses these ports from the modified environment, so I must export them before I run the app. Here is the code from the `postinst` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
echo "CUSTOM_PORT_1:$CUSTOM_PORT_1"
echo "CUSTOM_PORT_2:$CUSTOM_PORT_2"

export APP_PORT_1=$CUSTOM_PORT_1
export APP_PORT_2=$CUSTOM_PORT_2 

echo "APP_PORT_1:$APP_PORT_1"
echo "APP_PORT_2:$APP_PORT_2"
.
.
.
*run-the-app*
```

Unfortunately, this is the output:

```
CUSTOM_PORT_1: 
CUSTOM_PORT_2:

APP_PORT_1: 
APP_PORT_2:
```

I must mention I also tried the `subprocess.Popen` line in a few additional ways:

1.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo dpkg -i /path-to-package', env=my_env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

2. 

```
def open_process(command, app_vars=None):
    if app_vars:
        for key in app_vars:
           os.environ[key] = app_vars.get(key)

    p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'dpkg', '-i', 'path-to-package'], env={**os.environ}, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Are my expectations reasonable?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just learned that when running a command with `sudo` the local user environment variables are not the same as the root user.

In order to preserve the environment variables when running a command with `sudo`, you should add the flag `-E` as described in this answer [how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo).

I copied from [how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) the quote from the man page:

> -E, --preserve-env
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
> existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
> if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Once I changed the command string to `sudo -E dpkg -i path-to-package`, the `postinst` script was able to print out the variables as I expected:

```
CUSTOM_PORT_1: 7755
CUSTOM_PORT_2: 7766

APP_PORT_1: 7755
APP_PORT_2: 7766
```

Comment: BTW, `sudo env CUSTOM_PORT_1=7765 CUSTOM_PORT_2=7766 APP_PORT_1=7755 APP_PORT_2=7766 dpkg -i path-to-package` is an alternate working approach.