# sudo mvn --version and mvn --version shows different versions

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

When i did mvn --version it shows me version is 3.8.6

```
rohail@rohail-machine:/media/rohail/hard hdd1/http-request-plugin-master$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-48-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "UNIX"
```

When I did sudo mvn --version it shows me version is 3.6.3

```
rohail@rohail-machine:/media/rohail/hard hdd1/http-request-plugin-master$ sudo mvn --version
[sudo] password for rohail: 
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-48-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "UNIX"
```

I want the latest version of maven to be installed, I tried to remove the older one but failed to do so.

[image: This is the terminal image]

Comment: `Maven home: /opt/maven` vs. `Maven home: /usr/share/maven`!? (>privilged user's $path is different;)

Comment: /opt/maven is where i the downloaded maven manually

Comment: [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/592355)

Comment: sudo ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.8.4 /opt/maven

Comment: sudo nano /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

Comment: after this i added the following in maven,sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

Comment: `[sudo?] visudo` ... ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)