# Java SDK SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to fetch configuration properties from `Parameter Store` on boostrap application, for that I am using `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config:2.3.3` and I run the same configuration on Windows where it works but on linux ec2 instance or WSL2 I am receiving below error message:

```
AwsParameterPropertySourceNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

but before run it I am doing

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxx"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxx"
```

I also verify it using `printenv` and yes they are there. So the question is why I am receiving `...Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY...`does anyone know?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention but I use
`io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`
with configuration:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      access-key: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      secret-key: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    region:
      static: eu-west-1
      auto: false
      use-default-aws-region-chain: true
    stack:
      auto: false
```

But underhood it use [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) so it should works like AWS SDK for Java

Comment: Are you doing that in the same 'shell' window? Try replacing `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ` with `AWS_SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Upgrade to AWS SDK for Java V2 and use the cred providers documened in the DEV Guide:

 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've tried and I used the same console

Comment: `on linux ec2 instance` - why don't you just attach an IAM role to the instance?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Param Store is on totaly different AWS account

Comment: Are you sure your key ID and secret access key both work 100%? No typos for when you're doing an export?

Comment: @smac2020 But I don't think I need aws sdk for java when I am only using `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`

Comment: I use the Official AWS SDK and answer question with this in mind. The above API looks like a 3rd party AWS API.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes both works but when I am running them on Windows machine

Comment: For me it seems like my jar has no access to ENV properties. Using the  same console I export params then `java -jar ...`

Comment: Ok I found the issue. Problem was with that I export variables as user but run java jar as sudo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo