# Difference with sudo vs non-sudo in environment variables path

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Trying to understand something that I found interesting and confusing about host environment variable/paths. Couldn't find anything resembling this and I don't have enough CLI experience to know the right wording so hope you lot can help.

I was setting up an application that requires reading an environment variable that is set in `.bashrc` file.

```
export THIS_PATH=/this/location
```

Made sure to make it permanent. The variable then gets read in a docker-compose file for its location mapping.

`"$THIS_PATH/folder:/etc/folder"`

Running the command `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` yields an error going along the lines of

`WARN[0] The variable THIS_PATH is not set. Default to blank string`

Stumped me quite a while but I managed to resolve it by adding the user to the docker group, so I ran the command without getting any errors.

Curiously I used `printenv` with and without `sudo` to see the difference, and to my surprise the PATH wasn't in *sudo*.

**Question**

Is there a difference in environment paths between *non-sudo* and *sudo*? Can anyone explain to me about this?

I may have my terms wrong here and there. Hope you guys can correct me. Thank you in advance!

### Edit #1

Maybe I have to rephrase it.

Why the need for `sudo -E` if the environment variable is already in the *non-sudo* environment? Why doesn't *sudo* just use the already existing environment? Why the need of separation?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo answer your question?

Comment: In fact, `sudo` completely resets the environment; `sudo -E` will keep most variables, as described in the question @KamilCuk cites.  A Compose file can also interpret relative paths in most contexts, which could get around needing this environment variable.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the thread @KamilCuk and @David Maze. I understand using ```sudo -E``` solves it. Just wondering why the separation since my understanding that ```sudo``` would use the environment as is and not reset it. Maybe my understanding is still limited about that.