# Why doesn't docker build --build-arg propogate what's in the local environment?

Tags: docker

I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}
```

If I do something like `export PYTHON_VERSION=3.11` and `sudo docker build --build-arg PYTHON_VERSION .`, Docker returns an `invalid reference format` error. On the other hand, `sudo docker build --build-arg PYTHON_VERSION=$PYTHON_VERSION .` works as intended.

This seems contradictory to [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#-set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

> You may also use the --build-arg flag without a value, in which case the value from the local environment will be propagated into the Docker container being built:
>
> ```
> export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234
>
> docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY .
> ```

The version of docker I'm using is `20.10.23`. What's wrong here?

Comment: `sudo` won't use the current environment variables by default, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Comment: @IainShelvington Hah!!! That's it. I forgot `sudo` doesn't propagate environments. Thanks :D