# Secrets are not available in the GitHub Actions workflows

Tags: github-actions

I have added secret variables under the repository settings. Here are my objectives:

1. Read variables from secrets
2. Inject into the environment so application can read it.

## Issue:

Secrets worked fine with mysql initialization but nodejs code is complaining and throwing the error because environment variables are not there.

```yaml
# .github/workflows/nodejs.yml

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          # user: root, password: root (default)
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.employeeadmin }}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: MySQL Initialization Script
      run: |
        mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }} -p${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }};"
        mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }} -p${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }} ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }} < assets/schema.sql
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Start application
      run: sudo npm start
      env: # issue these variables are not available to nodejs app
        DATABASE_HOST: ${{secrets.DATABASE_HOST}}
        DATABASE_PORT: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PORT}}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE}}
        MYSQL_USER: ${{secrets.MYSQL_USER}}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD}}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}}
    - name: Run tests
      run: npm test
```

### Screenshot

[image]

---

Comment: Why don't you just set `env: DATABASE_HOST: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_HOST }}`, etc.? See e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#example-using-bash. Also they'll never be shown in plain text in the output, _because they're secret_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe see my edit for the earlier attempt, I had a blocker for env too

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in here, but do you see any problem with my earlier attempt? It's exactly like textbook example but not working in my case.

Comment: Could you inform the whole workflow file @AppDeveloper (or at least the whole job)? Not just the specific step where you set the env variables. To see if other configurations may impact the expected behavior here. (Also, note that [you can't use env variables in the same step you set them, only in subsequent steps](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)).

Comment: @GuiFalourd your comments tell me that syntax wise everything is okay with my attempt. Interesting in an earlier step, secrets work just fine with mysql. `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }} -p${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }} ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }} < assets/schema.sql`

Comment: To give you more context why the whole workflow could be useful here: If you set an [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) (not env variable) at the workflow job level, your secrets would need to be set somewhere else in your repo settings. And we can't identify this with your example as you're just sharing a few steps.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Updated with whole workflow file, screenshot of repo settings, and nodejs code. I hope this gives a good example.

Comment: Why are the credentials for the service _secrets_? It's only accessible from inside the network. But also the secrets context isn't exposed to the services: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts. Note your question hasn't actually said why you think it's not working - what's the problem?

Comment: I'm new to GitHub actions, not familiar with context, the problem is that nodejs code is complaining and throwing the error because environment variables are not there. If someone can tell what to fix in my yml file, I'll understand.

Comment: I'm under the impression that I should use secrets for username and passwords, or are you suggesting I should use plain variables if injecting any values to the nodejs application?

Comment: An actual [mre]: https://gist.github.com/textbook/1506d0ee70c392e5f29d3c61bbf0c1da. Secrets definitely still work.

Comment: still stuck guys, any idea on what's wrong? So the question is, Are secrets injectable to environments to be passed down to the application?

Comment: Even hardcoding values `DATABASE_HOST: 127.0.0.1`, nodejs can't access it. clearly there's something wrong with env

Comment: It's because you're running `sudo npm start`. You don't need to do that, but if you insist on sudo-ing you need to `--preserve-env`/`-E`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/3001761. This is nothing to do with GitHub Actions, it's how sudo works generally. And why it's so important to make an actual MRE: https://gist.github.com/textbook/dbf5d6972cff2bb1156b6adde2cdbffa

Comment: @jonrsharpe this `-E` works. gosh, man you could have come to the rescue a bit earlier. I saw how you reproduced it, but TBH I don't understand what you did there with the gist and shell scripts. I had to use sudo because of I'm running nodejs with certs, at 443 (is this wrong too?)

Comment: I didn't know the answer earlier! There was too much other context in the way and I couldn't recreate the problem (the first gist I shared was fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you've posted is completely irrelevant. The critical part of the workflow is this:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/push.yml

name: Playground

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - run: sudo npm start
        env:
          SOMETHING: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "gha-play",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```js
// index.js

console.log("something:", process.env.SOMETHING);
```

Running this, the output is:

```bash
Run sudo npm start
  sudo npm start
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    SOMETHING: ***
  

> gha-play@0.1.0 start
> node index.js

something: undefined
```

We can see that `SOMETHING: ***` is being set for the command (that's not the value of the secret, GHA replaces all appearances of strings it knows to be secrets with `***`), but `something: undefined` when the script runs. What gives? It's because you're using `sudo`, which (for security reasons) doesn't pass through all of the environment variables. Either:

- Don't bother with `sudo` at all:

  ```yaml
  run: npm start
  ```

  you shouldn't need elevated permissions; or
- Set `--preserve-env`/`-E` to pass the variables through:

  ```yaml
  run: sudo --preserve-env npm start
  ```

  per e.g. [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/3001761)

Either way, the secrets are now available to the running script via `process.env`:

```bash
> gha-play@0.1.0 start
> node index.js

something: ***
```

---

Also note that the `secrets` context is **not** exposed to `services`, per [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability):

| Workflow key | Context | Special functions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `jobs.<job_id>.services` | `github`, `needs`, `strategy`, `matrix`, `vars`, `inputs` | None |

so you won't be able to access them for configuring the MySQL container. But you don't *need* to keep these credentials secret; the container only exists for a short time and is only accessible from inside the network defined for that workflow's execution.

Comment: Great! one more thing and I'll be done here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWghQ.png GHA is spinning on the "Start Application", because server is holding the prompt, how can I run `node --test`, (and optionally shutdown mysql if required) and simply exit.

Comment: @appdeveloper a `run` step doesn't exit until the command exits. If you need the app and tests to run in parallel, consider e.g. `concurrently` (so you can use the same command locally as in CI, [example](https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/tech-products-demo/blob/f1b198743320573fba2feee26d4f936a0d086f29/package.json#L15)). Alternatively research how to background a step. Also no you don't need to explicitly shut down the services, GHA disposes of them when the job ends.

Comment: I did `run: nohup sudo -E npm start &` (nothing after &) and then another step with `npm test`. Please review.

Comment: > Also note that the secrets context is not exposed to services. and > But you don't need to keep these credentials secret; so can I hardcode default values `u: root`, `p: root` in my GHA file for mysql commands and application env?