# How to get directory where PHP script was called from

Tags: php, command-line

I have a PHP script in some directory. When I call it from the command line, getcwd(), `__DIR__` and exec("pwd") return the directory of the script itself, not pwd.

E.g. calling /some/place/test.php from /tmp:

```
echo(getcwd());        // prints /some/place

echo(exec("pwd"));     // prints /some/place

echo(__DIR__);         // prints /some/place

echo($_SERVER["PWD"]); // prints /tmp
```

$_SERVER["PWD"] has the value that I need, but it's not mentioned in docs http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost hit the "Post question" and guessed to check command line parameters. :-)

```
$ php -h
...
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
...
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was to use [getcwd()](http://php.net/getcwd).
The results I got from my tests where differents from yours.

**About $_SERVER['PWD']:**
As they explain in [Undefined index 'PWD' in $_server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564539/undefined-index-pwd-in-server), it is dangerous to use it.
As you said, it's not present in the documentation and it's not guaranteed that it's working as expected.

**About getcwd():**
This is the test I've done. Please consider that `testGetCwd.php` contains only a `echo getcwd();`.

```
// working dir: /home/me
// phpfile dir: /var/www/phpfiles

cd /home/me
php /var/www/phpfiles/testGetCwd.php
// echo /home/me
```

**Note:**
- Be careful if you are using `chdir` because is going to change the `current working directory.`
- It seems there is a change in functionality from `PHP 4` to `PHP 5`

All the above points may explain the behaviour you were experiencing.