# How to get document root path in PHP with CLI?

Tags: php

---

```
echo __DIR__;
```

"    How to get document root path in PHP from any subdirectory using command line?

```
my directory structure--

/dinesh
       /data
            /asset
```

Suppose my root directry is /dinesh

and currently my script in asset but I require document root path till /dinesh only

by using command line php CLI

How will I get this?

I have tried **DIR** and **FILE** but that give path till  asset and one more thing that dinesh is my local root folder  name that is changeable when I move my code to other server"

Comment: There is no DocumentRoot in a PHP CLI environment. Only in a webserver environment

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: Is this just a confusion in terminology? Are you looking for the Root folder of the disk? Or are you actually looking for the Apache `DocumentRoot`

Comment: whatever the folder where my code resides , it can be disk folder also

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905115/how-to-get-directory-where-php-script-was-called-from

Comment: Or `echo $argv`

Comment: can't you run 'pwd' command on CLI ? on linux it gives the absolute path of file

Comment: ok thanks will check it

Comment: echo($_SERVER["PWD"]); its working thanks RiggsFolly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo($_SERVER["PWD"]); its working

Answer (score 1):

try the code to get directory in php

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

Comment: take a look in this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894917/how-to-get-the-home-directory-from-a-php-cli-script

Answer (score 0):

In CLI mode there is no "root directory". If you do

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

you'll see that "DOCUMENT_ROOT" is empty. What you can use is

```
__DIR__; //asset
```

That will give you the path of the script, so you can go up any levels to get your "root directory" doing

```
dirname(__DIR__); //one level up 'data'
dirname(dirname(__DIR__); //two levels up 'dinesh'
```

But php cli won't know by himself what you are considering root directory because that's a constant of the web server.

Answer (score -1):

You can print the result that comes out of the global variable

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

And print

```
echo @getcwd();
```